# inputs are not sending to sql

Tags: php, sql

I'm building a "funds transfer" system that will make users on my website to trade with each other.

There are 3 buttons of the amount choosing a receiver input the info is sending to API successfully is the problem is probably in the API.

I have 3 buttons of 100-500-1000 dollars and an input field for the receiver.

The button script code is:

```
$("#btn1").click(
    function() {
        $.get(
            "api2.php",
            {
                "action":"insert100",
                "username":$("#reciever").val()
            },
            function( username ) {
                console.log(username);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

input code is:

```
<input type="text" id="reciever">
```

And the api.php code is:

```
    if (isset($_GET["action"])){
        switch ($_GET["action"]){

            case "insert100":

                    $cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("INSERT INTO users (money) value (100) WHERE username=:username");
                    $cursor=>execute( array( 100=>$_GET[100]), ":username"=>$_GET["username"] );

                        break;
```

P.S-I'm using xampp

Comment: Do you execute your prepared query? Does `username` matches DB value? Insertions should be send via POST, not via GET

Comment: yes, username matches DB value and for the POST you're right i changed that

Comment: Can you provide more info? As for now there is no error in code, but we don't see full picture.

Comment: yes, ill edit my post now and put a bigger part of my code= EDITED

Comment: Where you execute your `$cursor`?

Comment: below the the INSERT row

Comment: @xQwerty it seems like you have serious problems with your PHP syntax. First you have to learn PHP or hire a PHP professional, especially if you deal with real money. The problems I see are the following. 1. `cursor->execute( array(":username"="username") );   ` the `cursor` is a variable and thus should start with a `$`. The array assignment is wrong. You can't use `=`, you should have `=>`. 2. the `if` statements below the `break;` I am not sure if they break your code too. But for sure, the if statements they don't have reason to be there.

Comment: it just didn't copied well. edited and now its fine. the if's below was just an experiment i did before and deleted then. btw I'm not dealing with a real money its just for learn and fun

Comment: @Merianos Nikos